# Battery alarm command is not working in LXDE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxde, battery

I am using lxde desktop for my ubuntu 14.04. I have used synaptic package manager to uninstall some old files of qemu. But after that, I realize that some packages are removed from ubuntu eg: python IDLE,gedit etc.

Now the problem is that My Battery ALARM command is not triggering when critical limit is reached.

What should i do? I didn't find any solution on the web? Which package i have to install?

Comment: Yes, i wrote. But after that, i have changed it to xmessage command.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall indicator-power. This information is showed in history.log

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that 1) the battery alarm command *was* working (or would have worked), and 2) the reason it has stopped working is because you removed an important package.

Firstly, make sure you have the appropriate "meta package" installed for your Ubuntu flavour.  For LUbuntu, I think you should have `ubuntu-standard` and `lxde-core` installed, and if you're not sure, you should probably also have `lxde` installed.

Secondly, check for packages which are "recommended" by another package, but which you have removed.  The good news is `synaptic` has a built-in filter for this!  In the left hand panel, switch to "custom filters", and then select "missing recommends".

Sometimes this shows packages that aren't needed and sometimes it's not clear why.  But in general, it's a great way to look for packages that you might have been better off leaving installed :-).

If you have gone through these steps and the battery alarm command still does not work, the problem is likely caused by something else.